# Kubernetes: How to let Rancher Ingress LB listen to different IP address (not port)

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I experiment with Rancher Server on a RancherOS host which has multiple NIC interfaces / IP adresses:

- **eth0** - 10.30.0.231, used by

  - Rancher Server (Rancher API is running on 10.30.0.231:8080)
  - Rancher Agent (on the same host, since it is a test setup)
  - is connected to our IT management VLAN (only admins have access to is)
- **eth1** - 10.10.0.231

  - is connected with our internal office VLAN (all employees have access to it)

Now I wanted to create an Kubernetes Ingress which is exposing Ports on **eth1** Address but it seems the Kubernetes Ingress Controller of Rancher can only publish on the Rancher Agent IP since the Ports are only accessable through **eth0** IP address.

Is there any kubernetes Ingress annotation (like the `http.port`, as explained here: http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/kubernetes/ingress/#scale-and-other-port) which can be used to tell the Ingress Controller which IP/interface should be used for the Ingress??